# Safe using Websockets for multiplayer game?

Tags: node.js, networking, websocket, socket.io, multiplayer

I am developing a mobile game in unity and it will be real time multiplayer. I am looking for a networking solution and have come across building the networking part of my game using websockets (node.js server and some socket.io unity package). I am very new to networking and would like all the input I can get.

I am building a game where 25 people will be matched up at one time to fight one another. There will be multiple matches going on at once and I need the networking to work really well.

If Websockets isn't a good way to go, what else should I take a look at?

Answer (score 0):

Websocket is not the wrong choice definitely but make sure to stress test the environment as you need more than 1 servers, depending on the load.

You can follow this article: [Create a multiplayer game with React and socket.io](https://medium.com/@nikpundik/create-a-multiplayer-game-with-react-and-socket-io-eef36f06ba7d)

In this, they have used Artillery to stress test the system.

Comment: Awesome article. I guess one worry I have, and I don't know if it should be a worry, is that by making the game in unity and having to import (rely) on a third party publisher to support the SocketIO connection. Is this a worry? How hard would it be to make my unity scripts connect with a node.js app with socket.io?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to focus on your game, then you should use a commercial solution like Photon https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/1786

If you want to learn networking and protocols - I would start with the above as well (free) and then move in OSS frameworks.

Comment: How is Gamesparks for multiplayer?